# Merge two objects into one by key, keep duplicates

Tags: javascript, array-merge

So I have been looking for a solution to this for a while but can't seem to figure it out. I am trying to merge together the subscriptionArray and userArray by matching on the companyId, but if a company has multiple users (like companyA), I want the subscription Id to repeat and create a new object with a duplicate subscriptionId for each user (see the resultArray). I have a much larger data set i'm working with, but the end goal would be to have an array of every user as an object associated with a subscriptionId, with multiple repeating subscription id's for multiple users.

I am able to merge the two currently, but it doesn't create duplicate subscriptionId objects, it just replaces the previous object.

I can't use ES6, lodash or JQuery, so please just plain vanilla JS

```
var subscriptionArray = [
    {
     "subscriptionId" : 2,
     "CompanyId" : 20, 
    },
    {
     "subscriptionId" : 3,
     "CompanyId" : 30,
    },
    {
     "subscriptionId" : 4,
     "CompanyId" : 40,
    }
]

var userArray = [
   {"FirstName" : "Matt",
    "CompanyId" : 20,
    "CompanyName" : "CompanyA",
   },
   {"FirstName" : "Bob",
    "CompanyId" : 20,
    "CompanyName" : "CompanyA",
   },
   {"FirstName" : "John",
    "CompanyId" : 30,
    "CompanyName" : "CompanyB",
   },
   {"FirstName" : "Tim",
    "CompanyId" : 40,
    "CompanyName" : "CompanyC",
   }
]

var resultArray = [
  {
   "subscriptionId" : 2,
   "FirstName" : "Matt"
   "CompanyId" : 20,
   "CompanyName" : "CompanyA",
  },
  {
   "subscriptionId" : 2,
   "FirstName" : "Bob"
   "CompanyId" : 20,
   "CompanyName" : "CompanyA",
  },
  {
   "subscriptionId" : 3,
   "FirstName" : "John"
   "CompanyId" : 30,
   "CompanyName" : "CompanyB",
  },
  {
   "subscriptionId" : 4,
   "FirstName" : "Tim"
   "CompanyId" : 40,
   "CompanyName" : "CompanyC",
  },

]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You really should share what you have tried and what isn't working. That said this is fairly easy to do with `Object.assign()`

here is a fiddle that shows this in action https://jsfiddle.net/ysy50edf/1/

Lets check out the code:

```
userArray.forEach( function(user) {
  subscriptionArray.forEach( function(sub) {
    if( sub.CompanyId == user.CompanyId ){
        var result = Object.assign(user, sub);
      results.push( result );
    }
  });
});
```

Looping each user and then looping over the subscriptions to find the matching property. Then create a new result object that gets assigned the user and the subscription. This merges the two objects and then push that result into your results.

Comment: Thank you Drew! Unfortunately I can't use Object.assign because I am writing a script in Google Apps Script and the IDE doesn't recognize the assign function.

Comment: @MattMcCode you should clarify that in your question so that people understand limitations / environment.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific, I thought I had when I said I can't use ES6

Comment: Can you use the Polyfill? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: Hey Drew can you look at my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64058713/javascript-merge-array-and-keep-duplicate-based-on-main-array-key-value ??

Answer (score 0):

you could do it by using an intermediate structure `{[companyId]: items[]}` which would be the `userArray` indexed by company Id (and the values are arrays because multiple people can be in the same company). And then loop onto the `subscriptionArray` adn return a new correct value.

```
var userByCompanyId = userArray.reduce(function (users, item) {
    if (!users[item.CompanyId]) {
        users[item.CompanyId] = [];
    }
    users[item.CompanyId].push(item);
    return users;
}, {});

var subscriptionResultArray = [].concat.apply([], subscriptionArray
    .filter(function (item) {
        return userByCompanyId[item.CompanyId] !== undefined;
    })
    .map(function (item) {
        var subId = item.subscriptionId;
        return userByCompanyId[item.CompanyId].map(function (sub) {
            // deepMerge merge recursively objects, see loadash
            return deepMerge({}, sub, {
                 subscriptionId: subId
            });

        });
    }));
```

Note that I mutate the items in `userArray`, you can avoid this by using `Object.assign`in Es6 env or write your own implemantation.

Comment: This looks like it should work but I keep getting the error "Cannot call method 'concat' of undefined". I played around with it for a while and it seems like 'item' is not getting a value in subscriptionResultArray. Any ideas?

Comment: There was a typo in my code, it's `[].concat.apply` and not the reverse (arrays do not have a `concat` method).

Comment: So I think I worded my question poorly. @adz5A answered it perfectly, but I forgot to take into account two different subscriptions that have the same CompanyId. So for example if I added an extra object into the subscriptionArray with subscriptionId = 5 and companyId = 20, the subscriptionResultArray would return an array with every subscriptionId that matches 20, set to 5. It appears to be returning the correct amount of results though.

Comment: Hum, so a company can have more than one subscription Id ? You want to retrieve an array of `{ company, companyId, name, subIds: [id1, id2] }` ?

Comment: {
"subscriptionId" : 2,
"CompanyId" : 20,
"FirstName" : "Matt",
"CompanyName" : "CompanyA"
},
{
"subscriptionId" : 2,
"CompanyId" : 20,
"FirstName" : "Bob",
"CompanyName" : "CompanyA"
},
{
"subscriptionId" : 3,
"CompanyId" : 30,
"FirstName" : "John",
"CompanyName" : "CompanyB"
},
{
"subscriptionId" : 4,
"CompanyId" : 40,
"FirstName" : "Tim",
"CompanyName" : "CompanyC"
},
{
"subscriptionId" : 5,
"CompanyId" : 20,
"FirstName" : "Matt",
"CompanyName" : "CompanyA"
},
{
"subscriptionId" : 5,
"CompanyId" : 20,
"FirstName" : "Bob",
"CompanyName" : "CompanyA"
}

Comment: Kind of like that, where another subscription object is created for every user within the company associated with the subscription id. So like subscriptionId = 2 has has two results because the company has two users. SubscriptionId = 5 also has two results because it has two users, they just happen to be from the same company.  Then it would go to the next subscription and do the same thing. So imagine a company that can purchase many subscriptions, then I want a list of all the users in the company that purchase that subscription, but with a new object for every user.

Comment: So it's matching on companyId, but the 'primary key' I guess would be the subscriptionId, but the subscriptionId can repeat if the matched company has multiple users.